# Laravel 5 Delete a row from database

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, delete-row

I am trying to delete a category by clicking on a button but give me page not found.

[image]
**controller**

```
    public function ApagarPortfolio($id) {
        $i = DB::table('portfolio')->where('id',$id)->delete();
        if($i > 0) {
            Session::flash('apagarportfolio', 'Portfolio removido com sucesso'); 
            return Redirect::route('portfolio');                
        }
    }
```

**route**

```
Route::get('backend/portfolio/{$id}','BackendControlador@ApagarPortfolio');
```

**index**

```
                                        <a title="Apagar" href="{{URL::to('backend/portfolio/'.$portf->id) }}" style="color: white;">
                                            <button class="btn 
                                                @if($portf -> genero == 'Web Design')
                                                    btn-success btn-sm"                                                                             
                                                @endif   
                                                 data-widget="remove">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                            </button>
                                         </a>
```

Comment: change `backend/portfolio/{$id}` by `backend/portfolio/{id}` and test it again

Comment: omg the problem It was the $.
thanks a lot

Comment: lol... it happened to me tons of times

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
backend/portfolio/{$id}
```

to:

```
backend/portfolio/{id}
```